# how can i get user postalcode

Tags: swift, swift3, cllocationmanager

i'm using swift 3. I have problem with this code to get postalcode like this "US" and save it to var.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {                
            print("Location Error!")
            return
        }

        if let pm = placemarks?.first {                
            self.showlocation(pm)
        } else {
            print("error with data")
        }
    })
}    


func showlocation(_ placemarks: CLPlacemark) {

    self.locationm.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print("Location done")
   // getlocation = placemarks.postalCode! "this string var is nil"

}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    print("Location Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

There's no errors in code, but the app crashes founding nil, if i just removed "getlocation = placemarks.postalCode!"  the app wont crash, but i can't get the postal code. It was working on swift 2. Any help to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ashley-mills pointed out they are two different types of information. When ever you expect that a nil could be possible or even if you don't expect it the best solution is protect your self from cash with the something like the following.

```
guard let getlocation = placemarks.postalCode else { print("Returned Nil"); return }
print(getlocation) // notice no unwrap need
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by changing:

```
getlocation = placemarks.postalCode!
```

to:

```
getlocation = placemarks.isoCountryCode!
```

I don't know what's the difference maybe postalcode not working in swift 3?

Comment: `postalCode` and `isoCountryCode` are completely different things. One is like a ZIP code, or a UK post code, the other is the country code. Possibly you're in an area where there isn't a `postalCode` - but the real problem here is that you're force unwrapping variables. **Don't!**

Comment: oh thanks for explaining! I think "isoCountryCode" this is what i was looking for i just want to get country code to set a flag where the user from.